# WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE Syntax error at or near 'BY' (DBR 11.2 ML)

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I tried to execute the SQL statement below but the exception occurred.

```
MERGE INTO warehouse.pdr_debit_card as TARGET
USING (SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT CIF, 
      CARD_TYPE,
      ISSUE_DATE,
      MATURITY_DATE,
      BOO,
      DATA_DATE, 
      row_number() over (PARTITION BY CIF, 
        CARD_TYPE,
        ISSUE_DATE,
        MATURITY_DATE,
        BOO,
        DATA_DATE order by cif) as rank
      from staging.pdr_debit_card
      ) s where s.rank = 1 ) as SOURCE
ON TARGET.CIF = SOURCE.CIF AND
TARGET.CARD_TYPE = SOURCE.CARD_TYPE AND
TARGET.ISSUE_DATE = SOURCE.ISSUE_DATE AND
TARGET.MATURITY_DATE = SOURCE.MATURITY_DATE AND
TARGET.DATA_DATE = SOURCE.DATA_DATE AND
TARGET.BOO = SOURCE.BOO 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    STATUS = 'active'
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (
    CIF,
    CARD_TYPE,
    ISSUE_DATE,
    MATURITY_DATE,
    DATA_DATE,
    BOO,
    STATUS
  )
  VALUES (
    cast(SOURCE.CIF as string),
    cast(SOURCE.CARD_TYPE as string),
    to_date(SOURCE.ISSUE_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
    to_date(SOURCE.MATURITY_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
    to_date(SOURCE.DATA_DATE, 'yyyyMMdd'),
    cast(SOURCE.BOO as string),
    'active'
  )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND STATUS = 'active' THEN 
  UPDATE SET
    STATUS = 'inactive';
```

```
ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'BY'(line 26, pos 17)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND STATUS = 'active' THEN 
-----------------^^^
  UPDATE SET
    STATUS = 'inactive'
```

Based on this [doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into.html),
the above statement did follow the syntax reference.

Or this syntax won't apply to DBR 11.2 ML?

I have tried to included `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` and the exception was raised also.

Comment: I have figured this out, WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET support Databricks Runtime 12.1 and above

Answer (score 2):

I also tried with similar databricks runtime version getting same error.
[image]

As per [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/merge),Entries in the target table that are not matched by records in the source table can be updated or deleted using the `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` clause in **Databricks Runtime 12.1 and above**.

**The work around or solution is to upgrade your databricks runtime version to 12.1 and above.**

Now its executing fine:
[image]